# Not able to access environment variable from C/C++ Program

Tags: c++, c, linux, environment-variables

I am trying to access an environment variable from a C++ program. So I made a test program which works fine :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
   printf("MANIFOLD : %s\n", getenv("MANIFOLD_DIRECTORY"));
   return(0);
}
```

Output : `MANIFOLD : /home/n1603031f/Desktop/manifold-0.12.1/kitfox_configuration/input.config`

**Note : Signature of getenv is :**

```
char *getenv(const char *name);
```

But when I use this as a part of a bigger program with many files linked :

```
energy_introspector->configure (getenv("MANIFOLD_DIRECTORY"));
```

**Above does not work.**

```
char *a = new char [1000];
a = getenv("MANIFOLD_DIRECTORY");
energy_introspector->configure (a);
```

**Above also does not work.**

**Note : Signature of configure function :**

```
void configure(const char *ConfigFile);
```

**Error message :**

```
Number of LPs = 1
[Ubuntu10:18455] *** Process received signal ***
[Ubuntu10:18455] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[Ubuntu10:18455] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[Ubuntu10:18455] Failing at address: (nil)
[Ubuntu10:18455] [ 0] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x10330) [0x7f9a38149330]
[Ubuntu10:18455] [ 1] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(strlen+0x2a) [0x7f9a37dfc9da]
[Ubuntu10:18455] [ 2] /home/n1603031f/Desktop/manifold-0.12.1/simulator/smp/QsimLib/smp_llp() [0x5bf8c4]
[Ubuntu10:18455] [ 3] /home/n1603031f/Desktop/manifold-0.12.1/simulator/smp/QsimLib/smp_llp() [0x5a4ac6]
[Ubuntu10:18455] [ 4] /home/n1603031f/Desktop/manifold-0.12.1/simulator/smp/QsimLib/smp_llp() [0x5a4df8]
[Ubuntu10:18455] [ 5] /home/n1603031f/Desktop/manifold-0.12.1/simulator/smp/QsimLib/smp_llp() [0x4283b6]
[Ubuntu10:18455] [ 6] /home/n1603031f/Desktop/manifold-0.12.1/simulator/smp/QsimLib/smp_llp() [0x41e197]
[Ubuntu10:18455] [ 7] /home/n1603031f/Desktop/manifold-0.12.1/simulator/smp/QsimLib/smp_llp() [0x41de7a]
[Ubuntu10:18455] [ 8] /home/n1603031f/Desktop/manifold-0.12.1/simulator/smp/QsimLib/smp_llp() [0x41d906]
[Ubuntu10:18455] [ 9] /home/n1603031f/Desktop/manifold-0.12.1/simulator/smp/QsimLib/smp_llp() [0x41710b]
[Ubuntu10:18455] [10] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5) [0x7f9a37d95f45]
[Ubuntu10:18455] [11] /home/n1603031f/Desktop/manifold-0.12.1/simulator/smp/QsimLib/smp_llp() [0x41697f]
[Ubuntu10:18455] *** End of error message ***
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun noticed that process rank 0 with PID 18455 on node Ubuntu10 exited on signal 11 (Segmentation fault).
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**But this works :**

```
energy_introspector->configure ("/home/n1603031f/Desktop/manifold-0.12.1/kitfox_configuration/input.config");
```

Comment: Could there be other calls to `getenv` inside `configure`? Each time `getenv` is called, it may invalidate the result of the last call.

Comment: @TheDark No. There is no call the `getenv()` from `configure`

Comment: There is almost never a justification for `new char[1000]` in C++. Either `std::string`, `std::vector<char>` or `std::array<char,1000>` would be better choices. In this case: `std::string a = getenv( );`

Comment: @MSalters but the function `configure` requires a `char*` not `string`

Comment: @PRP: That's why `std::string::c_str()` exists.

Comment: Did you try to print result of `getenv()` ?

Comment: @Serhio Its `NULL` I checked

Comment: Okay, is it NULL for all variables (e.g. well-known `PATH`, `PWD`, etc.) ?

Answer (score 3):

`getenv` returns a pointer to library-allocated memory that is *not owned by your program*. Your

```
a = new char [1000]
```

line shows you did not recognize this and seem to assume you need to supply the memory. That is not true, especially you *may never* free the memory returned by `getenv`.

(Even if that would be correct, the simple pointer assignment

```
a = getenv...
```

would still be wrong, as you're just swapping a pointer and not copying the memory. That line is a memory leak as you loose the pointer to the allocated 1000 chars)

If you want your program to own that memory so you can later `free` it, you need to copy it into our private memory space.

```
a = new char [1000];
e = getenv (<whatever>);
strcpy (a, e);
```

Unfortunately, I cannot see what you do with the pointer later on in your other examples, especially if you try to `free` or `delete` it. Both will lead to an error.

Comment: What is your solution ? Is there any ?

Comment: btw....`a = new char [1000];
e = getenv (<whatever>);
strcpy (a, e);` does not work

Comment: copying to my own memory space....I tried to do that....still same error

Comment: In this case the problem is not in the code you showed us and you have another one. Compile using `-g` flag, please and update your question with a new stack dump.

Comment: Its already compiled with -g flag. See I am compiling/linking a set of libraries...and running a simulation using some benchmarks....using mpirun...

Comment: Ah, I see. Obviously, your program is falling over in `strlen` - You didn't show us any code that uses that function.

Comment: I am not using any `strlen()`...Although I can see that clearly in the logs...but lets assume that the `configure()` is calling it somewhere

Comment: maybe `getenv` returns NULL for some reason - you don't check for that.

Comment: I actaully checked..I used `secure_getenv` and checked for `NULL` to see that it is actually returning `NULL`

Comment: Then we're looking for a problem in a program you don't show us. How do you expect us to help, then?

Comment: Sir, this is a major bug in the library. What's the use of a String in the library's memory space if the other applications cannot be linked and used with it....Better approach would have been to take an output pointer as an input to the function which populates it and returns it back

Comment: @PRP Millions of programmers have coped with what you consider a "bug" during the last 30+ years. Maybe you can cope as well.

Answer (score 1):

First explicit error in your code is char array allocation and then assigning result of `getenv`. This leads to memory leak. In your case use:

```
std::string a = getenv("MANIFOLD_DIRECTORY");
```

This saves the result in variable `a` and makes your code immune to unsetting environment variables.

If `getenv` returns NULL then variable with specified name is not in the environment passed to your application. Try to list all available environment variables with code like below.

```
extern char** environ;

for (int i = 0; environ[i] != NULL; ++i) {
    std::cout << environ[i] << std::endl;
}
```

If your variable is not listed then most probably it's the problem how you call your application. The other option is that your environment has been unset.